# MongoDB: Map-Reduce with count

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

In my MongoDB I have a table with log entries that track activation/deactivation of processes:

```
user_id, time, event
```

Where event is one of 'start' or 'stop'. What I would like to generate out of this table is aggregated views that give me statistics of running (active) processes aggregated per hour, day, week and month.

Comment: Could you give some sample input/output data just to be sure about the structure?

Comment: This might be a unperformant schema for this particular query, instead a better one would be to have a process row which conains all of the data instead of one row for start and one for stop

Comment: Also, what is your question? What can't you make work? Please show us your attempts.

Comment: why don't you use aggregation framework instead of map/reduce?

Comment: also sounds like you don't care about which user_id did whatever they did?  or is user_id how you identify the process?

Comment: also do start and stops have to match up or is it possible to have for the same process a sequence start stop stop stop start start and if so do you care?